# Why is my collection being modified when I drop a database?

Tags: c#, linq, collections, foreach, smo

I have the following collection:

`IEnumerable<Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database> snapshots = svr.Databases.Cast<Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database>().Where(some condition);`

And I am iterating over it and dropping these databases:

```
foreach (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database snapshot in snapshots)
{
    snapshot.Drop()
}
```

(There's a lot more going on in this loop, but this is the only thing I could thing of that would be relevant to the problem.)

When the loop reaches its second iteration, I get an InvalidOperationException because the collection has been modified.

Why is this happening?

(Note:  calling ToList on `snapshots` does fix the issue, but I'm more interested in the mechanism by which `snapshot.Drop()` is modifying my collection.  I guess it might have something to do with deferred execution, but I'm not sure.)

Comment: Unfortunately the documentation is very unclear on this. I assume that `Database` "knows" which `DatabaseCollection` it's part of, and deletes itself from that when you call `Drop`.

Comment: Wherever you delete items from a list in a for lopp you have to remove from the end like this : for(int i = smapshots.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--){ snampshot[i].Drop();}

Comment: @jdweng I'm not removing it from the collection directly.  the Drop function has some side effect.

Comment: I guess that the Drop() method takes 'snapshot' out of svr.Databases which is the base of your iteration. Therefore your collection gets modified.